# Visual Studio Code Java Project export location

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, export

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Java Extension Pack for a java application.

[image: Visual Studio]

As you can see in the image above, the downwards facing arrow button exports my project to a Jar, which is saved to the project folder.

Is there an option anywhere I can set the export location, or post-build events where I can copy the jar to another location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not contains this feature and the settings to configure it for now. You can copy the jar file to anywhere you want and if it forces users to choose a place to put the jar file before creating it, that's tedious and a waste of time.